# how to insert my own form into ready Codepen template of search bar

Tags: html, css, django, codepen

Guys i have ready search input which i took from CodePen which looks great.

```
<div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
            </div>
```

I have the form which work good but is ugly :

```
<form method="POST" >
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form}}
                 <button lass="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></form>
```

I want to combine my form into ready CodePen template instead of input. However when i tried:

```
<div class="input-group">
           <form method="POST" >
             {% csrf_token %}
             {{ form}}
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button></form>
          </div>
            </div>
```

the box does not get size of the first one and does not work. Overall it does not get the share and parameters of the Codepen template.  What i missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form}}
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Submit </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Move your `</div>` before `</form>` tag.